# CakePHP add common code for each request

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using cakephp 2.6,I have a scenario where I have to update a database table column "last_request" whenever current loggedin user hit any url of the website.
I'm new to cakePHP, Please suggest me where I can implement common code(for ex: component etc) so that all request can be managed without calling that code specifically from each function or controller.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer suggested by @Dave, probably the best solution and answer given by @Ayaou works well apart from the possibility of code repetition.

What I want to share is these things can be done through [Authorization](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what) within 
AppController as well.

```
public function isAuthorized($user) 
{
   $userTable = ClassRegistry::init('User');
   $data = ['last_request' => $last_request_data];
   $userTable->id = $user['id'];
   $userTable->save($data);
}
```

The same thing can be done with afterFilter as well.

Comment: That's a good possible solution, depending on the project needs, but unless I'm mistaken, will only be triggered on actions that aren't already "allowed" as opposed to "all" actions like the OP asked.  Just something for people to keep in mind.  But I like this as an answer to keep on this question, as it could certainly help future devs and I'm sure is something some people will want to use.

Comment: Yeah Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add an `afterFilter()` method to your AppController. ([details here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::afterFilter))

> **afterFilter:** Called after every controller action, and after rendering is complete. This is the last controller method to run.

You could optionally use the beforeFilter() if you'd rather the code update earlier or one of the other [Request-Lifcycle callbacks](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#controller-life-cycle).

Then, you can add a method in your User model that will do what you want (update the user's row with the `last_request` field).

In the afterFilter() method, make sure the User model is loaded, then call it's method.  After every request, the afterFilter will be triggered, and your model's code will be run.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in the `Model` associated with  your table

I assume here that the table name is `users`

```
<?php
    class User extends AppModel{

        public function updateLastHit($id, $value){
            $lastID = $this->id;
            $this->id = $id;
            $result = $this->saveField('last_hit', $value); 
            $this->id = $lastID; 
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Then you call this function when the controller action logic has finished,  `afterFilter`  is the appropriate method to use

From a `AppController` for example

```
public function afterFilter(){ // afterRender
    //Set the variable $value
    $userModel = ClassRegistry::init('User');
    $userModel->updateLastHit($this->Auth->user('id'), $value);
}
```

Comment: This would require doing exactly what the OP asked to not have to do: call it in every action.

Comment: You are right Dave, I just updated my answer based on yours and @Manohar answer.

Comment: It's not acceptable practice to change an incorrect answer to mirror another existing answer created by someone else.

Comment: My intentions were to provide a correct answer, and sorry if i mirrord you knowledge, sir !